# Charting data store entity count

Tags: google-app-engine

To track my app growth, I would like to see a chart of how many new entities of a certain type are created in the data store per day.

I thought about creating a cron job that at midnight would store the count of all entities created in the past 24 hours, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Mixpanel and Google Analytics. Whenever I create a new entity, I fire an event to these third-party analytics services. Then I get nice charts to look at later without having to schedule my own cron jobs or make any charts.